# How to display camera view in VR mode?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, virtual-reality

I want to display camera view into VR mode for headsets. Can't find any sample of how to do it on Google documentation or Google.

In theory, I suppose that I must display two cameras at once, or something similar each one with 50% of the width of the screen, but not sure if this is the correct way to solve this problem. Also proportions must be respected. It's a little frustrating to not finding any info or guides about how to achieve this.

I'm sure must be easy ways to achieve it, because a lot of apps that shows camera in VR mode are present on Google Play.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm also interested!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a late one but this is exactly what you are looking for. Try the 'gvr-vuforia' sample from the project
link: https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.